# Eclipse Color Theme - Hard to read javascript in jsp editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

I've been using the Eclipse color theme plugin, and it's been great so far - However there's one problem/setting I can't seem to figure out how to change - it's occurring when I try to edit javascript in a jsp page - when I choose a dark color theme (Monokai in this case), Eclipse highlights the code with a javascript tag with a light highlight (see attached pic).

Does anyone know if there's a setting I can change in eclipse to change or remove this, or if it's even possible to change?

[image: A hard to read highlight]

Comment: what version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: same problem here. have you find any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well.

Short Answer:
Window -> Preferences-> MyEclipse -> Files and Editors -> Javascript -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring -> Background

More Answer:
You have to poke around for a while, but it seems like everything is *somewhere* in the Window -> Preferences path, and not necessarily where other related things are.

There's one section for html, one for jsps, and another for all the javascript inside of both of those, for example. One for global defaults (which others inherit... sometimes), etc. The key phrase to look for is "Editor"- then you know you're probably going to be able to configure the color of something.